# React Hook Number + Number save into a new data is that posible?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For example I have 2 sizes small and medium. How can I save both data add together into one new totalCount Data or any best practice to code below code, please

```
const [sizeSmall, setSizeSmall] = useState(0)
const [sizeMed, setSizeMed] = useState(0)
const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState(0)   // This will be sizeSmall + sizeMed add together

**// How can I make the total of both sizes into one total

<input 
type=number
value = {sizeSmall}
onChange = (e => setSizeSmall(e.target.value)
 required
/>

<input
type=number
value = {sizeMed}
onChange = (e => sizeMed(e.target.value)
 required
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now

```
const [sizeSmall, setSizeSmall] = useState(0);
const [sizeMed, setSizeMed] = useState(0);
const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setTotalCount(parseInt(sizeSmall) + parseInt(sizeMed));
}, [sizeSmall, sizeMed]);

return (
  <>
    <input
      type="number"
      value={sizeSmall}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setSizeSmall(e.target.value);
      }}
      required
    />

    <input
      type="number"
      value={sizeMed}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setSizeMed(e.target.value);
      }}
      required
    />

    <p>Total Count: {totalCount}</p>
  </>
);
```